# How to send data from NewsxWebPart.ts file to Newsx.tsx file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sharepoint, spfx

I have tried using this.properties but i'm getting value as undefined in Newsx.tsx file.I'm able to get this.props.description in News.tsx file, But not this.props.data. I'm setting the data in OnInit() which is a async method

Below is my NewsxWebpart.ts file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as ReactDom from 'react-dom';

export interface INewsxWebPartProps {
  description: string;
  data:any;

  }

var newst = new Array ;
export default class NewsxWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<INewsxWebPartProps> 
{
    public async onInit(): Promise<void> 
    {
       /* ajax calls to get data */
       /* getting the data inside the variable "newst"*/
       this.properties.data = newst
    }
    public render(){
      /* rendering*/ }
}
```

And Here is my News.tsx file

```
import * as React from 'react';
import styles from './Newsx.module.scss';
import { INewsxProps } from './INewsxProps';

export default class Newsx extends React.Component<INewsxProps, {}> { 

constructor(props:any){
 super(props);
 }
componentDidMount(){
 console.log("Hello "+this.props.description);
  console.log("Hello "+ this.props.data);

}
 public render(): React.ReactElement<INewsxProps> {
  return ()}
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take passing page context from webpart to component as example(this will be use often).

In component property interface,add the property which you need to get from webpart(.ts).

The context will pass from .ts.

```
import { WebPartContext } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
export interface IPnpReactProps {
  description: string;
  context: WebPartContext;
}
```

In webpart(.ts) file, the context will pass to component(.tsx).

```
public render(): void {
    const element: React.ReactElement<IPnpReactProps > = React.createElement(
      PnpReact,
      {
        description: this.properties.description,
        context:this.context
      }
    );

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement);
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, But the problem is i'm getting the value from an asyc call.   "context:this.context" this is called first before i get the value. I tried setTimeout but not working. Before this method there is a async oninit() method from this i'm getting the context value.